# How to prevent my snackbar text from being truncated on Android?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am displaying a snackbar with a fairly long text message and on the phone in portrait mode it looks fine.

[image: Phone Portrait mode]

But on the tablet it seems to only allow 1 line of text so it gets ellipsis-ed

[image: Tablet Landscape mode]

Is there anyway I can get it to be 2 line in tablet landscape?

Comment: as per the design guidelines snackbars should not contain lots of text, a snackbar should display a single small line of text. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#

a dialog is better suited here

Comment: As per the guidelines, the developers are not very smart. There is no way to measure text, and internationalization further makes that a complex issue.

Resolution: build your own in-app-notification-system, since the default provider jumped off a bridge.

Comment: Tap on truncated text to open expanded view would have been sufficient..., but magically disappearing notifications, are actually useless unless the user is babysitting the screen. Would have probably made a nice game of WHACK-A-MOLE, trying to catch the notes before they disappear...LOL

Answer (score 51):

What's important and not stated in other answers is that you need to use **Snackbar's view**.

So:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, R.string.message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
TextView snackTextView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);

snackTextView.setMaxLines(2);
snackbar.show();
```

Note: This may also help with devices with lower screen density.

***P.S If you're not using AndroidX (which is recommended), and are still using the legacy support libraries, please use `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` instead of `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text` for getting the Snackbar's internal TextView.***

Comment: you Rock bro :)

Comment: Nice simple answer, saved my time. I've updated the answer with AndroidX dependencies! Cheers!  :D

Answer (score 29):

You can reference the SnackBar's TextView like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
```

And then operate on the TextView itself by changing its max lines:

```
tv.setMaxLines(3)
```

Comment: Can't get reference to the SnackBar TextView. I get NULL from that statement.

Comment: @zulkarnainshah look at my answer - I clarified everything there

Answer (score 25):

Based on [Snackbar source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/snackbar/res/values-sw600dp/config.xml) you can see that on devices with width more or equal than 600 dp they change max lines to `1`. So You can also just add:

```xml
<integer name="design_snackbar_text_max_lines">3</integer>
```

into your `res\values\*.xml` values

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 4):

A more elaborate and thorough example with context would be this:

```
// Create on click listener
final  OnClickListener positiveButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    // Do your action - e.g. call GooglePlay  to update app
    openGooglePlayAppUpdate();
  }
};

// Create snack bar instance
Snackbar sBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.some_view_to_bind),  // You bind here e.g. layout, or form view
                              R.string.snack_bar_message,
                              Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        // Set text and action to the snack bar
                        .setAction(android.R.string.ok, positiveButtonClickListener);

// Now get text view of your snack bar ...
TextView snckBarTv = (TextView) offerUpdate.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
snckBarTv.setMaxLines(5); // ... and set max lines
sBar.show(); // and finally display snack bar !
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Kotlin you can make use of extensions

```kotlin
fun Snackbar.setMaxLines(lines: Int): Snackbar = apply { 
    view.findViewById<TextView>(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text).maxLines = lines
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution was auto-size within 2 lines:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar.Text" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView" >
    <item name="autoSizeStepGranularity">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="autoSizeMaxTextSize">16dp</item>
    <item name="autoSizeMinTextSize">10dp</item>
    <item name="autoSizeTextType">uniform</item>
</style>
```

You can also increase the max number of lines or change any other TextView attribute:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar.Text" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar.TextView" >
    <item name="android:maxLines">3</item>
</style>
```

And customize the button and paddings:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar.Button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar" >
    <item name="android:paddingStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>  
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>     
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0.0</item> 
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Snackbar" >
    <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Your theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="snackbarStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar</item>       
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar.Button</item>
    <item name="snackbarTextViewStyle">@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.SnackBar.Text</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [setTextMaxLines](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#setTextMaxLines(int)) method from the Snackbar class. It is now supported. The default is 2.